# Pass a function as prop which returns some jsx template

Tags: reactjs, react-native, prop

If I directly pass map function as a prop, it works. But it gets ugly.
Is there a better way to approach this. I want to make it look cleaner.

```
<FoodInfo info={restaurant?.menu.map((item, index) => (
  <View key={index} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{height: Sizes.height * 0.35}}>
      <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.image} />
    </View>
  </View>
 ))}
/>
```

But if I separate it out and then pass it as prop it does not work. It gives me an error

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
> return a Component instead of `<Component/>` from render.

```
//Separated

  const infoFunc = () => {
    restaurant?.menu.map((item, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{height: Sizes.height * 0.35}}>
          <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ));
  };

//pass the function

<FoodInfo info={infoFunc}/>
```

Comment: The cleaner way IMO is to pass `info={restaurant.menu}` and do the map inside the FoodInfo component .

Comment: Your function returns nothing, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns nothing because it's missing a return statement

```
  const infoFunc = () => {
    return restaurant?.menu.map((item, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{height: Sizes.height * 0.35}}>
          <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ));
  };
```

or use round brackets:

```
  const infoFunc = () => (
    restaurant?.menu.map((item, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{height: Sizes.height * 0.35}}>
          <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ));
  );
```

---

When you want to pass components like this, you might consider passing them as *children*. Components are composable:

```
<FoodInfo>
    {restaurant?.menu.map((item, index) => (
      <View key={index} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{height: Sizes.height * 0.35}}>
          <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ))}
</FoodInfo>
```

Inside FoodInfo you can then get and render them from `props.children`.

Comment: My bad, I missed the return keyword otherwise should have used round brackets. Thanks!